# How to use observablehq D3 graph in React project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, observablehq

In react project, I would like to use a tangled tree graph like - [tangled-tree-visualization-ii](https://observablehq.com/@nitaku/tangled-tree-visualization-ii)

How can I use it? Since D3 is open source library, is above example code is also open source to use?

I m beginner in D3. So far, 
 1. Installed the D3 library with `npm install d3 --save`
 2. Created D3 basic bar chart to check d3 is working

Instead of bar chart wanted to use tangled-tree-visualization shared above. But it seems it uses generated minified runtime.js by observablehq.

BarChart.js

```
import React from 'react';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

import { Runtime, Inspector } from "@observablehq/runtime";
import define from "@nitaku/tangled-tree-visualization-ii";

class BarChart extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.drawChart();
    }

    drawChart() {
        const data = this.props.data;
        const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", this.props.width)
            .attr("height", this.props.height);

        const h = this.props.height;

        svg.selectAll("rect")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", (d, i) => i * 70)
            .attr("y", (d, i) => h - 10 * d)
            .attr("width", 65)
            .attr("height", (d, i) => d * 10)
            .attr("fill", "green")

        svg.selectAll("text")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .text((d) => d)
            .attr("x", (d, i) => i * 70)
            .attr("y", (d, i) => h - (10 * d) - 3)

        //selection.attr(“property”, (d, i) => {})
    }

    render() {
        return <div id={"#" + this.props.id}></div>
    }

}

export default BarChart;
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import BarChart from './BarChart.js';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    data: [12, 5, 6, 6, 9, 10],
    width: 700,
    height: 500,
    id: "root"
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <BarChart data={this.state.data} width={this.state.width} height={this.state.height} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: hi, you might want to check their tutorial on how to embed it on a react application. https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/how-to-embed-a-notebook-in-a-react-app Because there is a runtime compiling their flavored javascript, you have to use it in order to mount on you react app.

Comment: @cal_br_mar - thanks for throwing some light on it.

Comment: hi I've added a full response with an example, as it was fun to make it work inside stackoverflow, hopefully this is useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example following their [guideline](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/how-to-embed-a-notebook-in-a-react-app) but using react hooks.

When the component is mounted, you have to instance the runtime, specify the cells you want to mount and the html nodes, in this case using `ref` to point to a `div` element

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const runtime = new Runtime();
    runtime.module(notebook, name => {
      if (name === "animation") {
        return new Inspector(animationRef.current);
      }
       if (name === "mutable speed") {
        return {fulfilled: (value) => {
          animationSpeed.current = value;
        }};
      }
    });
  },[]);
```

`animationSpeed` is a reference to a `mutable speed` cell from the observable notebook. When there is an updated on the react input range you `useEffect` to update inside the notebook, using `animationSpeed` reference

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if(animationSpeed.current){
    animationSpeed.current.value = speed;
    }
  },[speed]);
```

Here is the functional example.

ps. there is a bit o hack to load the modules inside stackoverflow code snippets

```js
const {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useRef,
} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [speed, setSpeed] = useState(1);
  const animationRef = useRef();
  const animationSpeed = useRef();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const runtime = new Runtime();
    runtime.module(notebook, name => {
      if (name === "animation") {
        return new Inspector(animationRef.current);
      }
       if (name === "mutable speed") {
        return {fulfilled: (value) => {
          animationSpeed.current = value;
        }};
      }
    });
  },[]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
  if(animationSpeed.current){
    animationSpeed.current.value = speed;
    }
  },[speed]);

  return (
  <div className="App">
    <small>Speed: {speed}</small>
    <input type="range"
            min="0"
            max="5"
            step="0.1"
            value={speed}
            onChange={(event)=> setSpeed(event.target.valueAsNumber)} />
     <div ref={animationRef}></div>

  </div>
  );
};

// Render
ReactDOM.render( <App / > ,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
<script type="module">
  import {Runtime, Inspector} from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@observablehq/runtime@4/dist/runtime.js"; import notebook from "https://api.observablehq.com/@observablehq/how-to-embed-a-notebook-in-a-react-app.js?v=3";
  // hack to make module packages global, so the babel transpile code can see it
  window.Runtime = Runtime;
  window.Inspector = Inspector;
  window.notebook = notebook;
</script>
```